# Where can I find info about specific file(s) on the system?

Tags: linux, files, i3, battery

I was building a simple battery level monitor (in `bash`) for my personal `i3blocks` implementation. It's quite obvious that the info I need is available in files in the `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0` directory. Of particular interest seem to be files `capacity_level`, `charge_full_design`, `capacity`, `charge_full`, `charge_now`, and `status`. Although, I think I know what the values in these files mean; I am only guessing due not having found any documentation on them...

For said use-case, is there any guide/resource I could consult to know for sure what values these files store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `/sys` (not `/proc/sys`), your best bet is to look at the documentation in [the ABI tree](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/); in your case, [`sysfs-class-power`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-power), which describes all the entries you’re interested in. For example:

```
What:       /sys/class/power_supply/<supply_name>/capacity_level
Date:       June 2009
Contact:    linux-pm@vger.kernel.org
Description:
        Coarse representation of battery capacity.

        Access: Read
        Valid values: "Unknown", "Critical", "Low", "Normal", "High",
                  "Full"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Documentation` directory under the `/usr/src/linux` path of your running kernel implementation is a huge resource.

I think that what you are actually looking for lies there :

**/usr/src/linux/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-power**

There may be distros which do not install the Documentation tree, forget them or... search the web for the way to install it by yourself.